# Trying select and download specific using express and node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, arrays, mongodb, express

My problem is I'm trying to make my web have the ability to slect a file and download.My explanation isn't clear but here is my code.
Frontend:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import './DisplayPage.css';
import NavBar from "../NavBar/NavBar";

export default function SingleDoc(){
    const{id} = useParams();
    const[place,setPlace] = useState(null);
    const[downld,setDownld] = useState('');
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(!id){
            return;
        }
        axios.get(`/staff/${id}`).then(response =>{
            setPlace(response.data);
        })
    },[id]);
    if(!place) return '';

    async function downloadButton(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        await axios.get(`/download/${id}`).then(response =>{
            setDownld(response.data);
        })
        alert("Success?");
    };

    return(
        <div>
            <NavBar/>
            <div className="single-doc">
                {place.profile.length > 0 && place.profile.map(photo => (
                        <div key={photo}>
                            <div>
                                <img className="file-pics" src={`http://localhost:4000/uploads\\`+ photo} alt=''  />
                                {photo}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                ))}
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={downloadButton}> Download</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So in this my code displays all the files stored under a folder. I can download the whole folder but i also want to be able to select a file from the folder and download it but i don't know what to do.
Backend:

```
app.get('/download/:id', async(req,res) =>{
    const {id} = req.params;
    const staffDoc = await Staff.findById(id);
    const x = __dirname + "/uploads/";

    res.zip(
        staffDoc.profile.map((p) => ({
          path: x + p,
          name: p,
        })),
      );
});

app.get("/single-download", (req, res) => {
 
});
```

Here is my backend where the api is sent to download the folder but as you can see don't know how to download a single file from the folder.
Here is also how the file names are stored in mongodb.
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUKxQ.png)

I tried to download based on id but dont know how to get the specific file i selected from the array.

Comment: please provide a minimal runnable demo, such as `codesanbox` https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what's the data of `staffDoc.profile` and `place.profile`, you need to add more details to your question.

Comment: @xgqfrms I dropped a photo showing the contents of staffDoc.profile and place.profile

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)